# Access specific Data using MySQL and Python

Tags: python, vba

I'm trying to get my SQL query to read the table gpsdata and get the values where the year is 2021. This code is throwing back an error. Does anyone know how I could solve it?

```
start_date = dt.date(2021,1,1)
end_date = dt.date(2022,1,1)

SQL_gpsdata = pd.read_sql_query(
    '''select
      date,
      car_id,
      disance_km
      from fleet_gpsdata
      where date >= %s and date < %s''',(start_date,end_date), dbconnect)

df_gpsdata = pd.DataFrame(SQL_gpsdata, columns=['date', 'car_id', 'disance_km']) #column names and sql query
df_gpsdata.sort_values(by = ["date"],inplace = True)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database0.py", line 49, in <module>
    where date >= %s''',(start_date,end_date), dbconnect)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 332, in read_sql_query
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1633, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1584, in execute
    cur = self.con.cursor()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I even tried

```
SQL_gpsdata = pd.read_sql_query(
    '''select
      date,
      car_id,
      disance_km
      from fleet_gpsdata
      where date >= dt.date(2021,1,1) and date < dt.date(2022,1,1)''', dbconnect)

df_gpsdata = pd.DataFrame(SQL_gpsdata, columns=['date', 'car_id', 'disance_km']) #column names and sql query
df_gpsdata.sort_values(by = ["date"],inplace = True)
```

Traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database0.py", line 51, in <module>
    where date >= dt.date(2021,1,1) and date < dt.date(2022,1,1)''', dbconnect)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 332, in read_sql_query
    chunksize=chunksize,
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1633, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1598, in execute
    raise ex from exc
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'select
      date,
      car_id,
      disance_km
      from fleet_gpsdata
      where date >= dt.date(2021,1,1) and date < dt.date(2022,1,1)': (1370, "execute command denied to user 'himani'@'%' for routine 'dt.date'")
```

Comment: Please include error traceback in your question.

Comment: if error shows problem in SQL query then you could test query directly in database using program `mysql` or any databasa viewer/editor like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/). It may show mode details about problem in query.

Comment: we can't run your code, we can't read in your mind - you have to add details in question (not in comment). always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Sorry about that. Have included the traceback errors in both cases.

Comment: So your first error is as I said because of wrong text formatting. Practically you are passing `(start_date,end_date)` as your DB connection, and it thinks your `dbconnect` is your `chunksize`. That's why everything is messed up.

Comment: read documentation for [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html) if first version you have to put `dbconnect` as second element and use `params=(start_date,end_date)` as next argument.

Comment: in second version you use `dt.date()` in query but SQL doesn't have this function - because it is Python code. You should use normal strings. Or you should put Python code using `f-string` with `{...code...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not formatting your query text right, in python if you're using the `%s` placeholder, you should use % out of the text to replace the `%s`. like: `"Hello %s" %"world!"` . In general, I believe f strings are more convenient to use. so try using:

```
my_query = ("select date, car_id, disance_km from fleet_gpsdata "
      f"where date >= {start_date} and date < {end_date}")
SQL_gpsdata = pd.read_sql_query(my_query, dbconnect, parse_dates='date')
```

In your second try, you're inserting the python object inside the string which is going to be treated like a string, not a datetime object.
I'm just guessing where you went wrong in your code, but as others've said, you should include the traceback error message in your code, people can't read your mind or your computer's.

Comment: Hi, I tried the code you suggested. I recieved this error.

Comment: @KaranSaraogi which error? I was missing a space, try and see if that was the issue

Comment: yeah I added the space but for some reason it shows an empty dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I decided to import the Database and then just add a column called year and select only the year I needed instead. It's inefficient but it worked out

Comment: Try regular strings too. `"where date >= '2021-01-01' and date < '2022-01-01' "`